# How to get midpoint from range in string within a dataframe column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-analysis, stringr

I have a data frame which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNK5E.png).

How, using R codes, can I create a new column in the dataframe which holds the values of the midpoints of the age groups (such as 34.5 for "30 to 39 Years")?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example (dataset) along with your expected output. So everyone can test their ideas and see which one might be an answer. Therefore you need to add your dataset as a codejunk not as a image. Here are some information about reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. First extract the min and max year of each age group. And in the next step create the mean of min and max.

**Code**

```
df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min = as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(`Age Group`, "\\d+"))[1]),
         max = as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(`Age Group`, "\\d+"))[2]),
         midpoint = mean(c(min,max))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-min, -max)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  `Outbreak Associated` `Age Group`      midpoint
  <fct>                 <fct>               <dbl>
1 Sporadic              40 to 49 Years       44.5
2 Sporadic              140 to 149 Years    144. 
3 Sporadic              20 to 29 Years       24.5
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(`Outbreak Associated` = "Sporadic",
                 `Age Group` = c("40 to 49 Years",
                                 "140 to 149 Years", 
                                 "20 to 29 Years"),
                 check.names = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df <- data.frame(AgeGroup = c("30 to 39 Years", "40 to 49 Years", "50 to 59 Years", "100 to 109 Years")
```

You can do it one very long line.

```
df$AgeMean <- rowMeans(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(df$AgeGroup, pattern = "[:digit:]{1,3}"))),ncol = 2, byrow = T))
```

So let me break it up:

1. `stringr::str_extract_all` finds and extracts all groups of numbers 1 to 3 digits long
2. `stringr::str_extract_all` returns a list of two component character vectors. `unlist` convert it to a single character vector and `as.numeric` converts character to numeric
3. `matrix` packs the numeric vector in a two column matrix
4. `rowMeans` get us the mean age

Comment: Thank you so much! Such an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will hear that it is helpful to include a reproducible example when asking questions. I put that together here for you as an example (and for any others who wander in here) based on the image you provided.

```
##### Load General Packages                                   # install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)                                            # Installs family of packages in the tidyverse (dplyr, tidry, ggplot2, readr, purrr, tibble, stringr, forcats)

# Use this evironment option if you want your variables to be type 'character' versus type 'factor'
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)                             # This option surpresses auto factor creation on string imports  


df <- data.frame(
  outbreak_associated = c("Sporadic", "Sporadic", "Sporadic"),
  age_group = c("40 to 49 Years", "40 to 49 Years", "20 to 29 Years")
)
```

Once you have this, you could do some simple math to estimate the mode:

```
df_fnl <- df %>%
  # create numeric columns for the min and max of the age range for each age group
  separate(col = age_group, into = c("age_min", "age_max"), sep = " to ", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(age_min = as.numeric(age_min)) %>%
  mutate(age_max = as.numeric(gsub(" Years", "", age_max
  # calculate the mode
  mutate(age_mode = age_min + ((age_max-age_min)/2))
```

There might be more efficient options, though this will get the job done.